# Where is the getShortcutHtmlId() in Mage_Paypal_Block_Express_Shortcut?

Tags: php, magento, paypal

Where is the getShortcutHtmlId() in Mage_Paypal_Block_Express_Shortcut?

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $this Mage_Paypal_Block_Express_Shortcut
 */
?>
<div class="paypal-logo">
<?php $shortcutHtmlId = $this->getShortcutHtmlId() ?>
```

Couldn't find $this->getShortcutHtmlId() in the mage source code. Anyone know where this function is declared?
http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Paypal/Mage_Paypal_Block_Express_Shortcut.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hunter,

This is not a method that is defined in Magento, instead these are getter and setter method that are used extensively in Magento.

In the case above, this value is set on **Mage_Paypal_Block_Express_Shortcut** on line no **108** as follows :

```
    // set misc data
    $this->setShortcutHtmlId($this->helper('core')->uniqHash('ec_shortcut_'))
        ->setCheckoutUrl($this->getUrl($this->_startAction))
    ;
```

Then this is reteived by calling getShortcutHtmlId() in the controller.

Hope this clears your doubt.